# Is it possible to group messages by subject/conversation then by date (not date/time) in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

So as the question/subject states; Is it possible to group (or sort) by subject/conversation and then by the received date (NOT the received date and time) in Outlook 2016?

Basically, I have a crap ton of emails from a newsgroup. What I would like to do is somehow format the view so that the messages are grouped by conversation. Similar to thread sorting (I think that's what it's called). You know, the way messages are displayed on blog sites. Where the initial message is at the top and then the replies are beneath it, indented.

Comment: Not sure about "sort by received date not the received date and time". Could you provide a screenshot on it?

Comment: @SteveFan, not really... I tried to find an example of what I am looking for on the web and of course, when your needing to find an example, nothing comes up. As far as outlok goes, the date/time apparently is a "set in stone" value.